# using a ping command in c code

Tags: linux, networking, ping

I`am a beginner in coding so I would ask for help to using this code 
on raspberry buster in a c program:

`ping -c 1 -t 1 192.168.1.1;if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then echo "192.168.1.1 is up";
else echo "ip is down";fi`

the code should do 
1. if ip is up insert inputs from ig. a keypad to a mysql database
2. if ip is down write the inputs line by line a file

thank you very much for some tips.

Answer (score 1):

To ping yourself, your application would have to create a raw socket, needing the NET_RAW capability.
You may have look at the GNU iputils ping implementation for reference: https://sourceforge.net/p/iputils/code/ci/master/tree/ping.c

**Most convenient** would probably be "Execute `ping` as a process and parse its exit code".

Comment: Hi! but i don`t want a lot code, is there an other possibility ? Thank you very much for our answer in advance.